# SpringBoot Failed to bind properties under app

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot 2.1.7.RELEASE project with gradle. I'm getting an error when I try to use @ConfigurationProperties

The property that I'm trying to bind is existing in my application-default.properties and if I run the project using Itellij I can see that the property is ingested in my component.

If I enable @EnableConfigurationProperties I got an error.

My application-default.properties

```
app.forwarding-endpoint=localhost:8080
```

My AppProperties.java

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
@Validated
@Data
public class AppProperties {
   @NotBlank
   @Pattern(regexp = "^(.+):\\d+$")
   private String forwardingEndpoint;
}
```

My Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application .class, args);
  }
}
```

My component that is using the property:

```
 public MyComponent(@Value("${app.forwarding-endpoint}") String forwardingEndpoint) {
    log.info("Forwarding endpoint {}", forwardingEndpoint);
 }
```

The error that I get is:

```
Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'app' to com.config.AppProperties failed:

Property: app.forwardingEndpoint
Value: null
Reason: must not be blank
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you running the application when it doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause is in the order of initialization.
You did not fill AppProperties but start to use it in components. You need to annotate this class also as a component but it's not a good approach from point of view of an architecture.

The concept of @ConfigurationProperties is quite raw for Spring and without some manipulations, you will quite difficult to force it to work correctly. I propose a simple 'trick' (or 'another approach'):

```
@Data
public class AppProperties {
   @NotBlank
   @Pattern(regexp = "^(.+):\\d+$")
   private String forwardingEndpoint;
}
```

(I think the place of @validated is not in the entitity/DO).

And place in your @Configuration next code:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public AppProperties setAppProperties() {
    return new AppProperties();
}
```

And next, you can inject AppProperties bean in any component.